# ARMv8: can I jump from within BL1 to another address?

Tags: assembly, armv8

UPDATE: this is because the MMU memory attribute settings. I manually add the `0x8000~0x9000` region with `MT_CODE` as one of BL1's static memory regions (before enabling MMU), then it works fine.

---

I am new to ARM. Somehow I want to jump from within BL1 to another address (say `0x8000`), by adding two lines of code in `bl1_entrypoint`, right after the call to `bl_main`:

```
    bl  bl1_main

    mov x0, #0x8000
    br x0
```

However, it seems that the `br` instruction causes the system hang.

I also tried to put the jump in `bl1_main.c`, by adding a function `jump()`, and call it after entering `bl1_main()`:

```
void jump(void)
{
    NOTICE("BL1: entering jump()...\n");
    console_flush();
    asm volatile ("mov x20, #0x8000\n");
    asm volatile ("br x20\n");
}
```

As tested via JTAG, it also stalls at the `br` instruction.

If I change the address `0x8000` to `0x0`, then the behavior is expected that BL1 will keep repeated booting.

If I change the address `0x8000` to the address of jump() (`0xb00` by inspecting `bl1.dump`), it also behaves as expected.

I am a bit puzzled on why it can not jump a bit further (besides `0x8000`, I also tried `0x5000` which does not work either).

The code I put at 0x8000 (or 0x5000), is a similar jump code taken from `rom_trampoline.o` (changed the destination address to `0x0`). My goal was to test the behavior that BL1 jumps to `0x8000`, and then jumps back to `0x0`..., and the code jump back and forth forever.

From the JTAG debugger, if I set a break point at `jump()` (`0xb00`), it will stop at `0xb00`, pointing to the `movz x20, #0x8000` instruction, which is followed by `br x20` instruction. If I step over this instruction, JTAG debug will disconnect with the FPGA target, and reporting in its status bar "Error - Failed asm stepin ! - Unknown Error (0x00000002)". This is also unexpected, since in the beginning (at address `0x0`), I can step over instructions, also the `mov` instruction seems harmless...

I also tested with two trampoline code (i.e., no BL1 involved): placing one trampoline at `0x0` which jumps to `0x8000`, and then put another trampoline at `0x8000` which jumps to `0x0`. As tested, this works as expected as the two break points (`0x0` and `0x8000`) can be hit alternatively forever.

The mechanism of BL1 "jumps" to BL2 is a bit complex to me for now. I just want to know why the scenario described above does not work.

Thanks.

Comment: What you mean stalls? Do you see exception when you jump to 0x8000 ? If so can you read ESR_ELx register and decode ESR_ELx.EC, ISS fields to see the cause of error. 

Also are you sure if you have placed correct code at 0x8000 and code at this memory is executable.

Comment: @Shivakumar I updated the question to include the symptom of the "stall". When the system hangs, JTAG debug is disconnected to the FPGA target, I can not check registers any more. Also the trampoline code placed at 0x8000 should be ok as I tested with another scenario (also in the updated question). Thanks.

Comment: It's not supported (and therefore potentially unsafe, especially with optimization enabled) to jump out of an inline asm statement without telling the compiler about it, and to clobber registers without telling the compiler.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html.  Put both `mov` and `br` in one asm statement, and follow it with `__builtin_unreachable()` to let the compiler know that execution won't come out the other side.  (Since you won't be able to use `asm goto` to tell it about a jump to some absolute address that's not part of this function.)